# Java BCryptPasswordEncoder equivalent in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Is there any equivalent function or feature in `mysql` of `java BCryptPasswordEncoder` ?

**In java:**

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode("asdf");
```

**Result:** `hashedPassword` = `$2a$10$3IbqODV77Xrnga.LiiDaP.Oh5te4umnWstbwM3sx1eSMOqEVoxupe`

How can I get the same encrypted value for string `asdf` in `MySQL`?

Following are some failed attempts I made in `MySQL`.

<strike>`SELECT MD5('asdf');`</strike>

<strike>`SELECT SHA1('asdf');`</strike>

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `ENCRYPT(str, salt)`. There are some caveats though:

- It only works on Unix where the glibc function `crypt()` is available (it doesn't work on Windows)
- Not all distributions of Linux support Bcrypt (actually, most of them don't)

If you're using a Unix, then try something like this to see if your MySQL installation supports it:

```sql
SELECT ENCRYPT('myPassword', CONCAT('$2a$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Windows :( .